# Discord Python v2.0 | Pre-Select in Selection Menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am developing a DiscordBot in python with the Version 2.0

So, I have some Selection Menus, which I want to connect with a JSON.

Example:

```
file = open("./data/streamplan.json", "r")
data = json.load(file)
file.close()

list_monday = Select(placeholder="Montag:")
online_option = discord.SelectOption(label="Stream", value="online", emoji = "", description="Montag")
offline_option = discord.SelectOption(label="Stream", value="offline", emoji = "", description="Montag")
maybe_option = discord.SelectOption(label="Stream", value="maybe", emoji = "", description="Montag")
list_monday.callback = SelectionHandler.slc_streamplan_monday
list_monday.append_option(online_option)
list_monday.append_option(offline_option)
list_monday.append_option(maybe_option)
```

I want that my Bot already pre-Selects the option (online,offline,maybe) on start.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectOption` has a `default` attribute that you can set/pass as well.

Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=selectoption#discord.SelectOption.default

> Whether this option is selected by default.

Also, consider subclassing instead of manually overwriting the `callback` attribute. This is a really ugly way to go about it. There's an [example on GitHub](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/views/dropdown.py).